# Unsecured Chat when Dynamic Update is Enabled

Tags: dynamic, security

*Mathematica* v11.3 has just been released, A new feature, Chat, could be found In `File>New>Chat`. It is convenient when communicating code with other users, but it's quite unsafe as one can let the other users in chat evaluate certain code and return the result using chat and self-evaluating behavior of `Dynamic` contents.

Though turning off Dynamic Updating completely would solve this problem, but it could be quite inconvenient. Are there anyway to keep my computer safe as well as allowing dynamic content to evaluate?

Thanks!

Comment: Sample code for Let the other evaluate the value of `Prime@1000` and return it to you using chat could be found in the deleted answer of mine.

Comment: S.W. said in his [blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/03/08/roaring-into-2018-with-another-big-release-launching-version-11-3-of-the-wolfram-language-mathematica/) that "it’s sandboxed so people can’t send 'code bombs' to each other". This is worth pointing out, even though there can be problems that are not covered by the sandboxing.

Comment: @C.E. It is sandboxed in someway, e.g. `$ActivationKey` cannot be evaluated properly inside Chat. But there's actually **LOTS** of ways to get pass these restrictions... You should be able to see my deleted answer, where you let the other guy compute something and return it to you. I've tested this code as well as some more harmful ones with @happyfish... So it seems those protection are not that solid?

Comment: Here is an idea, find which stylesheet it is using and which style is used for output from people. Then edit the stylesheet and add to the style `DefaultFormatType -> InputForm`. No more fancy typesetting but hidden evaluation as well. (didn't test that yet)

Comment: @Kuba ah~ this might work~ In this way I can check whether the code is actually safe before I evaluate the code.